# about sizeof() class of different type

Tags: c++, size, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)

why the output is `8`?
not `sizeof(int)+sizeof(char) = 5`?

```
class CBase 
{ 
    int a; 
    char p; 
}; 

int main() {

    cout<<"sizeof(CBase)="<<sizeof(CBase)<<endl;
    getchar();
} ///:~
```

Comment: [structure padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof#Structure_padding)

Comment: more explanation here--> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Memory is usually aligned by the compiler for better performance. So a class or structure can take more space in memory than the sum of its parts.

Comment: Specifically in this case: if you create an array of `CBase` then the next element begins in the next byte after the previous one ends. So to ensure that `a` is 4-aligned in every element of the array, the implementation has padded `CBase` out to a multiple of 4. The size of a struct is always a multiple of its alignment requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Looks as if the compiler / run-time has aligned to an 8-byte boundary. You might find you can change this by compiler or runtime switches. For example, on AIX, C++ memory allocations are aligned to 16-bytes which can cause them to use more memory.

To not do this alignment, there's a way around this at runtime (which has the drawback that the apps can't use VMX) Just set this environment variable for the application prior to running it:

```
export LIBCPP_NOVMX=1
```

Comment: The compiler doesn't need to align to 8 bytes, it may just want to align `int`s to 4 bytes.